# Spring Integration Flow : Circuit breaker for each endpoints or at flow level

Tags: spring, spring-integration, circuit-breaker

I have successfully implemented some spring Integration Flow.

I am looking to have a circuit breaker either the same one for each endpoints or either at the flow level.
I have already read this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/handler-advice.html, but I havent find my answer.

Should I use some AOP ?

Thanks

G.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have missed in the mentioned docs, but `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice` is indeed over there: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html#circuit-breaker-advice

The advises like this should be applied in the Java DSL with this configuration option:

```
.transform(..., c -> c.advice(expressionAdvice()))
```

Pay attention to that `advice(expressionAdvice())` call. The `expressionAdvice()` is a bean method. So, you can do something similar for the `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice` and any your endpoints in the flow which need to be guarded by the circuit.

And yes, you can use only a single bean for the `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice`. It does keep a state for any endpoint it is called against:

```
protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
    AdvisedMetadata metadata = this.metadataMap.get(target);
    if (metadata == null) {
        this.metadataMap.putIfAbsent(target, new AdvisedMetadata());
        metadata = this.metadataMap.get(target);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer @artem-bilan.
I really appreciate that a spring integration team member anwsered to this.

After more thoughts, I have reformulated my problem.

Given an IntegrationFlow, with a specific error channel, if there are more than a given amount of errors in given span time (more than 10 errors in 10s), I want to stop polling the input channel.

So I redirect all the errors for this flow to the specific flow error channel.
An error counter is incremented, and then if the threshold is reached in the given span time, I stop the poller.

I have a second flow that monitor "stopped" pollers, and it restart them after some time.

[UPDATE]

I do have use your recommendations.
Mainly because I the framework dont solve your problem, your probably wrong.
And I was wrong.

Thanks !